# Apache Spark - Is it possible to compute N to N operations on same RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am currently developping an application with Spark in Python. I have a dataset of hotels as following:
Id, Hotel name, Addres, .... , longitude, latitute

I would like to compute, for each hotel, the top 5 hotel located near by.

Is it possible to do so in Spark ? I do not know if I can parallelize my RDD with my dataset, and then compute each line with the entire dataset.

---

So here is what I tried :
    test = booking_data.cartesian(booking_data).map(lambda ((x1, y1),(x2,y2)): distanceBetweenTwoPoints)

distanceBetweenTwoPoints is my function which calculates two points and taking four parameters.

The error displayed is : ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Perfectly possible. Give it a try.

Comment: Not certain I understand the question. You can .filter your data set by distance and then do a .top

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete comment: "Give it a try... and if it doesn't work, show us some code to be able to help"

Comment: I will do soon. Thanks for your help

Comment: this is not a Spark problem, it's a Python problem. You'd need to supply us with more code and tell us where that error occurs exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the grid-based search algorithm for efficient finding of top-rated hotels around each hotel, the idea is explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172378/3731823). The source code can be found from my [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/nikonyrh/bc8ef5fe87ffac7d2b89).

The algorithm is based on grouping hotels into "buckets" (cells of a grid) and to distribute each hotel also into its 8 nearby buckets. These are then brought together by groupByKey and analyzed independently from the rest of the data. I didn't run many tests for it but output looks reasonable. I hope this helps for future reference.