# Calculate farthest point of every point

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Suppose we have two sets of points, say A and B (both of size `O(n)`) in the plane. Can we find farthest pair of points each being in A & B in `O(n)` time?

Comment: Do you want to find farthest pair of points each being in A & B? I suggest you rephrase your question and add what you have you done so far.

Comment: @Rishit, Thank you. I changed it.

Comment: I don't think you could do it in O(n) time. But it is possible in O(nlogn) time.

Comment: yes..we can do in O(nlogn) time by finding convex hull or farthest point Voronoi diagram for the point set A. I would like to know whether better performance is possible or not.

Comment: By an information theoretical argument: simply producing the indexes of all farthest neighbors takes n bits per point, for a total of n Log n bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not calculate the furthest point for each point in `O(n)`. The best you can obtain is `O(n log n)` with a [2-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). You can do this with a technique, similar to finding a closest point.

Read a more detailed [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864864/1090562) where I show a couple of other approaches to solve a similar problem.

Comment: You got the green tick even though you seem to be answering the *closest* pair problem, not the *farthest* pair problem...?

Comment: @j_random_hacker essentially the same coz u can reverse the comparator

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: Maybe that works for the 2-d tree solution, I don't know, but it definitely doesn't work for e.g. the "grid" solution in the linked answer.  In general, if you know that a is close to b, and that c is close to a, then you know that c is at least somewhat close to b -- but if you replace "close to" with "far from", the inference fails.

Comment: @j_random_hacker the idea is the same for both problems. The question has not asked how to solve the problem, but rather asked whether it is possible to solve it in O(n). So my answer is `no`, and here is some explanation to a related problem. You can modify a grid solution - now you will need in the beginning to find the furthest grids, and check points in the furthest grids.

Comment: As you don't mention in the answer itself that it addresses only a related question, I'm going to -1.  Will undo if you mention there that closest point is just a related problem, and that some solutions to it can be adapted to the farthest point problem.  You also don't give any reason *why* there cannot be any solution better than O(n log n) (to either problem).

Comment: @j_random_hacker I modified it. One thing to mention is that is it really hard to prove that something can not be done with some complexity. For example there is not proof that matrix multiplication can't be done in O(n^2), or dijkstra can be done faster. In majority of such cases we just say that it can't be done now, because the best we know now is this complexity.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: That's (unfortunately) true in general, but in the case of the closest point problem, there is a reduction to the element uniqueness problem, which is one of the rare problems that has a known lower bound (in this case, O(n log n)).  I've removed my -1.

Comment: My -1 because there is no justification of the impossibility. Also, referring to a "similar" problem is often misleading. Think of Eulerian and Hamiltonian paths. Also, the approaches cited in the link have no guarantee of O(n Log(n)) efficiency.