# Simple k-nearest-neighbor algorithm for euclidean data with variable density?

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

An elaboration on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944649/suitable-choice-of-data-structure-and-algorithm-for-fast-k-nearest-neighbor-sear), but with more constraints.

The idea is the same, to find a simple, fast algorithm for k-nearest-neighbors in 2 euclidean dimensions.  The bucketing grid seems to work nicely if you can find a grid size that will suitably partition your data.  However, what if the data is not uniformly distributed, but has areas with both very high and very low density (for example, the US population), so that no fixed grid size could guarantee both enough neighbors and efficiency?  Can this method still be salvaged?

If not, other suggestions would be helpful, though I hope for answers less complex than moving to kd-trees, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this?

http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/major_section/1.4.shtml

kd-trees are quite simple to implement, there are standard java/c implementations.

Also:

You may want to post your question here:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many elements, just compare each with all the others.  This can be a lot faster than you'd think; today's machines are *fast*.  Unfortunately, the square factor will catch you sooner or later; I figure a linear search of a million objects won't take tooo long, so you may be okay with up to 1000 elements.  Using a grid, or even stripes, might boost that number substantially.

But I think you're stuck with a quadtree (a specific form of k-d tree).  Your whole map is one block, which *can* contain four subblocks (upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right).  When a block fills up with more elements than you want to do a linear search on, break it into smaller ones and transfer the elements.  (Only leaf nodes have elements.)  It's easy to search within a given radius of a given point.  Start at the top and if a part of a block is within range of the point, check out it's subblocks the same way if it has them.  If it doesn't, check its elements.

(When searching for "closest", take care.  The square grid means a nearer object might be in a farther block.  You have to get everything within a given radius, then check 'em all.  If you want the 10 closest and your radius of 20 only picked up 5, you need to try a larger radius.  You may have a rejected item that proved to be 30 away and think you should grab it and a few others to make up your 10.  However, there may be a few items at 25 away whose whole blocks were rejected, and you want them instead.  There ought to be a better solution for this, but I haven't figured it out yet.  I just make a guess at the radius and double it till I get enough.)

Quadtrees are fun.  If you can set up your data and then access it, it's easy.  The problems come when your mapped elements appear, disappear, and move while you are trying to figure out who's near what.