# Searching for "nearby" results

Tags: json, database, algorithm, database-design, geolocation

I have a dataset, currently just stored in a JSON file, which contains about 40k different geolocations. It looks something like this:

```
[
    {"title": "Place 1", "loc": {"x": "00.000", "y": "00.00000"}},
    {"title": "Place 2", "loc": {"x": "00.000", "y": "00.00000"}},

]
```

where a place's `loc` is just its coordinates.

I'd like to be able to run queries on this data so, for any given user-inputted `loc` I can get the `n` nearest Places.

Or in other words I'd like to write some function `f` so that this works:

```
def f(loc, n): ...
f({"x": "5", "y": "5"}, 3) #=> [{"title": "Place 1", "distance": 7.073}, {"title": "Place 2": "distance": 7.073}, {"title": "Place 3", "distance": 7.073}]
```

if there is a place 1, 2 and 3 all at `{x: 0, y: 0}`.

I have no idea what the standard way of solving an issue like this is. Using an SQL DB with an index on precomputed distances doesn't work, because the supplied `loc` is arbitrary. Running through the entire database and calculating distances for everything is far too inefficient, and far too slow. (I need < 30ms response times.)

The only solution that makes sense would be to somehow make "buckets" of close locations (within some `r` of eachother), and then to computer the distance between the user-given loc and the bucket's loc to narrow down the options first. But I feel like creating such a solution myself would be similar to not using databases at all; there must be a more efficient/industry standard approach. Is there one?

Comment: Postgres (with the PostGIS extension) has very good support for this type of queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalized form of the [nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Methods) problem (more formally known as [k-nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm)). You're right, the [solution that makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944649/suitable-choice-of-data-structure-and-algorithm-for-fast-k-nearest-neighbor-sear) uses buckets. You could store the buckets in the database which allows you to leverage SQL, just filter out all points not in the appropriate buckets. [Depending on your database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx), this actually may already be implemented for you, which would be the "industry standard" approach you suggested.

Otherwise, writing it yourself is pretty efficient and can be done without deviating too much from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database with a point data type and a spatial index like MySQL. You can also use a quadkey or a quadtree. It's subdivide the plane and reduce the dimension. You can download my PHP class Hilbert-curve@ phpclasses.org. It's uses a quadkey and can help to organize locations in buckets and build a proximity searching. A quadkey can reduce overlapping searches because of a special database.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides Spatial data capabilities. It has an inbuilt nearest neighbour function [SDO_NN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_operat.htm#i78067) which will do the job for you. Only overheard will be putting all the data in db, rest will be taken care of by oracle db.