# Is there a way to speed up this function to calculate K-Nearest Neighbor?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, knn

I am fairly new to programming and I have created a function to compute the 1 K-Nearest Neighbor (KNN1) to make predictions. The issue is, the code is so slow I cannot test it on the training set I really need. My training set is ~ 1200 x 5600 where there are 1200 data points and 5600 features. I need to compute the sum of squared differences for each feature in each row, then pick the other row that is the most similar. The below code takes HOURS and still has not finished. I believe the thing that is taking forever is the distance loops (triple for loop).

I have included a small training set from the sklearn IRIS dataset for testing.

If anybody has any suggestions to speed this up so that I may test my other code in a reasonable time frame, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np   

def l2_distance(row1, row2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(row1)):
        #print('row one: {}'.format(row1[i]))
        #print('row two: {}'.format(row2[i]))
        distance += (row1[i] - row2[i])**2
    return sqrt(distance)

def KNN1(x, y):
    # Create sum of square distances for each feature in each row
    d_arr = []
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        d_temp = []
        for j in range(0,len(x)):
            d = l2_distance(x[i], x[j])
            d_temp.append(d)
        d_arr.append(d_temp)
        #del d_temp

    # Find the index for the first NN
    idx_arr = []
    for i in range(0,len(d_arr)):
        temp = list(d_arr[i])
        m = min(j for j in temp if j > 0)
        idx_arr.append(temp.index(m))
        del temp

    del d_arr
    # Make a prediction based off the position in y_train for the test row
    y_hat = []
    for i in range(0,len(idx_arr)):
        y_hat.append(float(y[idx_arr[i]]))
    del idx_arr
    y_hat = np.array(y_hat)
    y_hat = np.reshape(y_hat,(len(y_hat),1))
    a = np.where(y==y_hat, 1, 0)    
    accuracy = float(np.sum(a,axis=0)/float(len(a)))*100.0
    return accuracy

iris = load_iris()
xtrain2 = iris.data[:, :2]
ytrain2 = (iris.target != 0) * 1
ytrain2 = np.reshape(ytrain2, (len(ytrain2),1))

acc = KNN1(xtrain2,ytrain2)
print('Accuracy for KNN (k=1) for the base dataset:\n\t{}\n'.format(acc))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suitable choice of data structure and algorithm for fast k-Nearest Neighbor search in 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944649/suitable-choice-of-data-structure-and-algorithm-for-fast-k-nearest-neighbor-sear)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to consider other algorithms to accelerate KNN, such as ball trees(which work well on data sets with a large number of features) or k-d trees. The optimization of the algorithm will reduce the time complexity exponentially.

---

But if you stick with brute-force search, the following information might be helpful:

Since you already use numpy, why not also use scipy to speed up your calculations. You can use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` instead of triple loops to get the distance metrix and `scipy.argsort` to find the index for the first NN.

I change your code into this:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy import argsort
from scipy.stats import mode

def KNN2(x, y):
    # Create sum of square distances for each feature in each row
    d_arr = cdist(x,x)
    d_arr += np.eye(x.shape[0])*np.max(d_arr)

    # Find the index for the first NN
    idx_arr = argsort(d_arr, axis=1)[:, : 1]

    # ! I don't touch this part
    # Make a prediction based off the position in y_train for the test row
    y_hat = []
    for i in range(0,len(idx_arr)):
        y_hat.append(float(y[idx_arr[i]]))
    del idx_arr
    y_hat = np.array(y_hat)
    y_hat = np.reshape(y_hat,(len(y_hat),1))
    a = np.where(y==y_hat, 1, 0)    
    accuracy = float(np.sum(a,axis=0)/float(len(a)))*100.0

    return accuracy
```

Testing on my PC:

```
%timeit KNN1(xtrain2,ytrain2)
# 51.4 ms ± 523 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit KNN2(xtrain2,ytrain2)
# 1.24 ms ± 26.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

One tiny-KNN that I implemented can be seen [here](https://github.com/CQU-AI/ML-Algorithm/blob/master/cquai_ml/KNeighborsClassifier.py).